# Regular Expression Split XML in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to split some XML text into parts:

```
xmlcontent = "<tagA>text1<tagB>text2</tagB></tagA>";
```

In C# i use

```
string[] splitedTexts = Regex.Split(xmlcontent, "(<.*?>)|(.+?(?=<|$))");
```

The result is

```
splitedTexts = ["<tagA>", "text1", "<tagB>", "text2", "</tagB>", "</tagA>"]
```

How can do it in Java?

I have tried

```
String[] splitedTexts = xmlcontent.split("(<.*?>)");
```

but the result is not like my expecting.

Comment: What is the result you got from the Java split ?

Comment: The parameter to `split` defines the *delimiter* to split at. You seem to want to *find* matches.

Comment: have you any function in java line the function in C# that i mention

Comment: @Minh Le: You can use the [`regex` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) to find matches or refine the pattern to find delimiters as in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter to `split` defines the *delimiter* to split at. You want to split before `<` and after `>` hence you can do:

```
String[] splitedTexts = xmlcontent.split("(?=<)|(?<=>)");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xmlContent = "<xml><tagA>text1</tagA><tagB>text2</tagB></xml>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<.*?>)|(.+?(?=<|$))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlContent);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```